GaxiosError: Login Required. when I deall with commentThreads.insert function using Youtube_api and Node.js quickstart.js
I've modified quickstart.js file provided by youtube api(node.js version), and I have done my Api_key and credential.josn file, so I successfully run the function of getChannel() and getVideos(), however, when I run the function insertComment, I've got this erroe from the console:
Error inserting comment: GaxiosError: Login Required.
at Gaxios._request (/Users/chi/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:136:23)
I want to successfully sent the comment to the video by using the api function

codes shown below is my modified quickstart.js file:
var fs = require("fs");
var readline = require("readline");
var { google } = require("googleapis");
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",
];
var TOKEN_DIR =
  (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || process.env.USERPROFILE) +
  "/.credentials/";
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + "youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json";

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile("client_secret.json", function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error loading client secret file: " + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), insertComment);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url: ", authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", function (code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error while trying to retrieve access token", err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != "EEXIST") {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Token stored to " + TOKEN_PATH);
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function getChannel(auth) {
  var service = google.youtube("v3");
  service.videos.list(
    {
      auth: auth,
      part: "snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
      id: "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    },
    function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
        return;
      }
      var videos = response.data.items;
      if (videos.length == 0) {
        console.log("No channel found.");
      } else {
        console.log(
          "This channel's ID is %s. Its title is '%s', and " +
            "it has %s views.",
          videos[0].id,
          videos[0].snippet.title,
          videos[0].statistics.viewCount
        );
      }
    }
  );
}

function getVideoos(auth) {
  var service = google.youtube("v3");
  service.search.list(
    {
      auth: auth,
      part: "snippet",
      q: "green day",
    },
    function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
        return;
      }
      var videos = response.data.items;
      if (videos.length == 0) {
        console.log("No videos found.");
      } else {
        console.log(videos);
      }
    }
  );
}

function insertComment(auth) {
  var service = google.youtube("v3");

  const commentParams = {
    part: "snippet",
    body: {
      snippet: {
        videoId: "EGcF7lyqN8Q", // its an hard-coding id of a video which permits commenting
        topLevelComment: {
          snippet: {
            textOriginal: "speechless...", // this is what I want to comment
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  service.commentThreads.insert(commentParams, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error inserting comment:", err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Comment inserted successfully:", response.data);
  });
}

